# Etiqueta embed en HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdf

Dentro de la atiqueta `embed` cargo un pdf, cuando ya esta cargado en la consola de firebox puedo ver el contenido del DOM y veo que la etiqueta `emdeb` tien de hijo a #document que asu vez tiene de hijo a una etiqueta `<html>` y esta asu vez a muchos `div`, ect. como puedo acceder por jquery a estas etiquetas? intente asi: `$('#embed > #document')` y no me deja.

Siguiendo el camino (emdeb>#document>html), dentro de html hay muchas etiquetas, por ejemplo `<div id="outerContainer">`, Como puedo obtener el html de este div?, intente haciendo esto `$("#outerContainer").html()` y no funciona.

Comment: Por favor actualiza tu pregunta añadiendo lo que necesitas obtener de ese pdf, el código que hayas intentado y el (o los) error(es) que puedas tener.

Comment: Que veas cómo Firefox representa internamente el PDF, no quiere decir que lo puedas manipular o que el método que encuentres te vaya a funcionar en otros navegadores. Lo más probable es que no funcione en ninguno de los dos casos

Answer (score 0):

si usas `#` en `jquery` para seleccionar elementos esta indicando que es un id, lo que necesita es llamar la etiqueta como tal:

```
$(documet).ready(function(){
    $("embed").find("document", function(){
         //aqui el resto del codigo
    });
});
```

espero sea de ayuda

Comment: Esto es incorrecto. El hecho que el OP vea `#document` al inspeccionar el DOM **no quiere decir que exista** dicho elemento. Lo que el usuario está viendo **es el documento** del recurso externo que ha cargado mediante `embed.` Si quieres acceder al documento interno de algún elemento incrustado, hay otras formas.